# Extensive revision of a question, or ask a new question?

Tags: discussion

[This](https://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/2977/what-would-happen-if-the-entire-world-switched-to-the-4-day-work-week) question was put on hold (for good reasons I think) but it prompted me to think a bit about how the underlying question could be addressed from a theoretical perspective. I mentioned a bit of this in my comment to that question. The OP added enough in the comments that I think the question could be re-worded and reworked to make for an interesting "thought experiment" question.

It would entail some extensive re-writing, though. Would it be better to simply post a new question, perhaps with a link back to the "motivation" (even if it is closed)?

As an aside, I think that "very open" questions are often potential fodder for theory or empirical applications. They may need to be fleshed out a bit and one may need to ask "under what sort of model is the question likely to occur." It may be the case that the necessary model is simply intractable, or has no good theory developed, or no data exists which could be used to estimate or calibrate the models -- thus the question is (at least currently) unanswerable in a rigorous way.

Aside 2: this process -- turning a "too open" question into a potentially answer-able research question -- is one aspect of the "grad cafe" that I'd love to see develop here on Econ S.E.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the appropriate response here is to edit the existing question and then flag it for a moderator's attention for potential re-opening.

The objective should be to have a single great example of each possible question, rather than crowding the site with multiple iterations on the same question.